# Codeigniter form validation - at least one field is required

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a submit form with 3 fields. At least one of the field should be filled in before submitting. Could you please help me to do it with codeigniter form validation.

**controller**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country','trim|strip_tags');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('state','State','trim|strip_tags');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','trimstrip_tags');
```

Comment: I think you should extend validation class

Comment: if you want validation before submit you should do that in `Javascript / jquery`.  server side validation will work after posting a form and using this rule you can validate `$this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country','required');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a guru, but that will be my approach...

```
function do_add()
{
   if( (isset($_POST['country']) || (isset($_POST['state']) || (isset($_POST['city']) )
   {
      //Do stuff
   }
   else
   {
      //Redirect or whatever
   }
}
```

Comment: in your code only city field is required, I need at least one field is required

Comment: @EducateYourself Ok, i have changed my code. Is this what you want? The u can pass validation rules for alpha/trim/etc if one of the following values in `$_POST` are set.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('country','Country','trim|strip_tags|callback_validate_either');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('state','State','trim|strip_tags|callback_validate_either');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','trimstrip_tags|callback_validate_either');
```

Add callback validation function

```
function validate_either(){
    if($this->input->post('country') || $this->input->post('state') || $this->input->post('city')){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_either', 'Please enter atleast one of City , State or Country');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

By the Codeigniter Documentation, the error message was set by passing the name of the method (without the “callback_” prefix):

Answer (score 0):

If copied code, there is lack of one pipe in third rule. Also, you would set `required` rule as first rule for each.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country','required|trim|strip_tags');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('state','State','required|trim|strip_tags');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','required|trim|strip_tags');
```

[CI Rule Reference](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use custom validation

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country','trim|strip_tags|callback_validate_either');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('state','State','trim|strip_tags|callback_validate_either');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city','City','trimstrip_tags|callback_validate_either');
```

then adding validation function

```
function validate_either(){
       if($this->input->post('country') || $this->input->post('state') || $this->input->post('city')){
            return TRUE;
       }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_name', 'Please enter atleast one of City , State or Country');
        return FALSE;
       }
    }
```